# Is there a way to use the brms function bayes_factor without having to refit models to not have prior samples?

Tags: rstan

In the brms package the function bayes_factor allows you to compare two models. Personally, I prefer the WAIC or LOO methods of comparing, but it is helpful to have both these and bayes factors for those who like bayes factors for these purposes.

I fit my models with the option to save prior samples in order to be able to use the hypothesis function to obtain Savage-Dickey Bayes Factors for point null hypotheses. Because of this attempting to use the bayes_factor function to compare whole models throws the error message " Models including prior samples are not usable in method 'bridge_sampler'."

Is there a way to get rid of the prior samples or make bayes_factor ignore them in order to use this function without having to wait what can sometimes be a very long time to refit my models without the prior samples?

Again, I'm aware of the superiority of WAIC for model comparison, but not everyone I communicate results with feels that way.